# Dynamic function calls

Tags: c, function, runtime

How do you write a runtime-dynamic function call in C which would take a variable number of arguments during runtime?

For example, consider `long sum(int count, ...);`, which returns the sum of the values of the (integer) arguments passed to it.

```
$./a.out 1 2 3 4

10

$./a.out 1 2 3 4 -5

5
```

Comment: Are you sure you're asking the right question? The problem you describe is much better solved with a loop that reads from the standard input or loops over the arguments rather than with a variable function.

Comment: Just use argc and argv.

Comment: I accept that. I'm trying to find out if C supports this feature.

Comment: @sssv96: Please give a better, more representative example of the problem you want to solve. As for stdargs, no, you cannot build an argument pack statically with the C standard library facilities. You would instead pass a dynamic array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't. Alas, you only can call a variadic function with a given number of arguments, but not with an array.

Depending on the architecture, you can call the function "behind" the variadic one - the one which takes a `va_list`, provided there is one, such as `vprintf()` "behind" `printf()` - with the array's address, but *that would be highly unportable*. Better don't do this.

The best would be to create a 3rd function, such as:

```
long asum(int count, long * arr)
{
    long s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < count, i++) {
        s += arr[i];
    }
    return s;
}

long vsum(int count, va_list ap)
{
    long s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < count, i++) {
        s += va_arg(ap, long);
    }
    return s;
}

long sum(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    long ret = vsum(count, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return ret;
}
```

This `asum()` would be the one you'd call. But this only works with an intermediate array which you convert the command line arguments to.

Maybe an additional `ssum()` would help:

```
long ssum(int count, char ** arr)
{
    long s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < count, i++) {
        s += atol(arr[i]); // I am not sure if this is very portable; if not, choose another way.
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of main is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

You can then access the arguments that are provided when the program.

Just parse those. Do the maths. Spit out the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Oh how the stack overflow is full of such nay-sayers.

Look at this library: http://www.dyncall.org

You can build up dynamic argument lists, and then execute an arbitrary function.